# Osascript requiring argument I think it already has. Python/Terminal

Tags: python, unix, heredoc

Using python I am experimenting with """ strings and osascript. So what I have is this

```
os.system("""arch -i386 osascript -e
                      ' tell application "Finder"
                        activate
                        display dialog "Hi"
                        end tell'""")
```

This is being run from Python, but it keeps telling me that

```
osascript: option requires an argument -- e
usage: osascript [-l language] [-e script] [-s {ehso}] [programfile] [argument ...]
```

I don't know about you, but I see a -e in my statement. No lack of that. What's going on?? Do I need to specify a HEREDOC inside of it (What I believe is a Python Heredoc), for Terminal to read?

Comment: The Python heredoc syntax won't remove newlines, maybe that's what confuses the shell. Try putting the first line of the script on the same line as the `-e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Python heredoc / double-quoted string syntax preserves newlines and other whitespace in the string. Apparently, this breaks the `system()` call somehow. Getting rid of the offending newline and making the script string start right after the `-e` should work.